# How do I set up early fraud warnings with Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'd like some assistance from anyone who is familiar with setting up early fraud warnings with Stripe and a Wordpress/Woocommerce website.

What exactly would I need to do in order to set this up?

This noob thanks you in advance for your assistance :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring the `radar.early_fraud_warning.created` [events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-radar.early_fraud_warning.created) emitted by [early fraud warnings](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/measuring#early-fraud-warnings) requires operating a [webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). You'll need to work with WordPress and/or WooCommerce to understand whether this is something they can support.